# Remove UIColor CGColor - KVC warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, key-value-coding, kvc, cgcolor

How to remove `[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]` stupid warning?

```
[self setValue:
     [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor] 
          forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_View_%@%d.layer.borderColor", 
              i>=10?@"":@"0", i]];
```

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'CGColorRef' (aka 'struct
>   CGColor *') to parameter of type 'id'

thanks.

Comment: -1 without comment. You are cool man!

Comment: +1 with comment: first search hit answered my question :-)=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cast CGColor to id type:

```
[self setValue:
     (id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor] 
          forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_View_%@%d.layer.borderColor", 
              i>=10?@"":@"0", i]];
```

Comment: Works, but it's strange because if I use `id color = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];` warning remain the same...

Comment: cast it (as he said) :: the problem is that CGColorRef isnt really an NSObject and thus not compatible (with arc for example. it doesnt know retain/release/isEqual ...) -- for methods that accept that know this, this isnt a problem so above code is save

Answer (score 0):

This will perform same as above code.

```
[self setValue:
 (id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor] 
      forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_View_%02d.layer.borderColor", i]];
```